# Printing to PDF from ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, printing, pdf

When clicking Print > Adobe PDF the filesize is nice and small but the legend gets messed up.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I am aware of the Export > PDF and of the reduce DPI and Re-sampling sizes.

Comment: Could you define "messed up"?  Perhaps include a screenshot of the legend after printing to a pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Print ->Adobe PDF then what you're actually doing is using a print-driver to create the PDF. The problem therefore is with whatever PDF print driver you're using.

Try using a different one there are some comparisons here:

- [The best freeware virtual PDF printer: a comparison](http://www.freewaregenius.com/2011/06/16/the-best-freeware-virtual-pdf-printer-a-comparison/)
- [General list of PDF Software (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software)

Myself I use the free and Open Source [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) with no problems.